# OpenSSL ECC named curve support

Tags: ecc

I tried searching online but can't seem to find whether or not OpenSSL support both NamedCurve.arbitrary_explicit_prime_curves and NamedCurve.arbitrary_explicit_char2_curves? As far as I can tell bouncy castle are the only SSL/TLS implementation that supports it, any others that anyone known of?

Comment: `openssl ciphers` will list supported ECC ciphers. `openssl ecparam -list_curves` will list the specific curves. But the names you refer to I don't recognise in the openssl list. Even if openssl does support your curves under a different name, they might only be available for `s_client` mode (i.e. SSL/TLS but not files). And GnuPG 2.1 with ECC hasn't been released yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code for arbitrary curves is in the library; see [the source code](http://www.openssl.org/source/), file `crypto/ec/ec_lcl.h`, in particular function `ec_GFp_simple_group_set_curve()`. The OpenSSL code includes specialized function for some specific curves (in particular NIST curves) but also has functions for the general case.

Code for encoding and decoding arbitrary curve parameters in ASN.1 (e.g. for use with a public key in an X.509 certificate) also appears to be present (in `crypto/ec/ec_asn1.c`). However, I doubt this code gets much used, since most of the rest of the world supports only a few specific curves; so even if the code is there, it was probably not thoroughly tested.

Comment: But it seems like we can't use arbitrary curves for SSL/TLS connection. Or am I right?

Comment: Arbitrary curves are supported at the protocol level (see RFC 4492, section 5.4) but I am not sure whether OpenSSL implements it. The EC code is there (at least for prime fields), but maybe not the glue at the TLS level. Of course, if you control both sides, you could just define your own "named curve".